# Javascript: Appending second dropdown selection to URL

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have two dropdowns in my webpage. How do I append the second dropdown selection to the URL without using.

```
window.location.href +="&selected2="+value2;
```

please tell me what change I must to the the function setsecondparam where value1 is the selection from the first dropdown.

```
function seturl(sel){        
var value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
window.location.href = "website.php?selected1="+value;
}

function setsecondparam(sel,value1) 
{
 var value2 = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;

 window.location.href ="website.php?selected1="+value1+"&selected2="+value2;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use one function. I wrote it more or less in ES5, you can change it to ES6 if you use babel.

```
function insertParams (key, value) {
    let search = window.location.search;
    let regex = new RegExp(key+"=[^\&]*");

    search = search.replace(regex, key + '=' + value);
​
    if (!regex.test(search)) {
        search += (search.length > 0 ? '&' : '?') + key + '=' + value;
    }
​
    document.location.search = search;
}
```

Comment: Hi, If I select another value in my dropdown this would append that value as well to the URL so I'd have multiple values for the same key. Which was why I didn't want it appending to the url but instead changing the value for the key.

Comment: @RP, Try it now. I added regex to check if key is there

Comment: Hi Leo, 
I need it to replace the previous parameter value with the new parameter value. Can you suggest how I could do so as now I cannot change the dropdown value after the first change. I tried replacing the parameter by ""

Comment: @RP, I edited it. It should work now with replace also